# How to remove Change Desktop Background from right click?

Tags: scripts, desktop-background, administration

I want to restrict users on changing wallpapers and themes. So can anyone say me how to remove 
**Change Desktop Background** option from right click?

**Note:**

I just totally want to remove that option from right click.

Comment: This doesn't look possible without recompiling from source. I'll clone the repo and see where the code is.

Comment: Do you want to remove access to `gnome-appearance-properties` entirely, or just this method of accessing it? If you want to prevent users from customizing their background or theme, you probably just want to remove access to the command entirely (require supervisor password to continue or something).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you can live without icons on your desktop, you can disable right click menu entirely through Nautilus' show_desktop option like this:

```
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop false
```

Edit: Getting rid only of that menu entry would require patching the Nautilus source. The menu definition is in `src/file-manager/fm-desktop-icon-view.c` inside `desktop_view_entries[]` (or just search for `Change Desktop _Background`). *Edit2: See below for HowTo.*

Other option would be to use different file manager to draw desktop icons. Maybe PCMan File Manager doesn't have this entry in right-click menu?

### Minimal guide to editing & rebuilding Nautilus

As I've noted before, the menu entry is hardcoded to Nautilus, so as far as I know, the only way how to remove it AND keep all other functionality is to edit Nautilus' source and recompile it. Be warned that it will take some time and you'll need some space for all the development packages and compilation itself.

The process was tested with Nautilus Elementary 2.32.2.2, however there shouldn't be any differences for stock Nautilus 2.32.

1. Get basic development packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev devscripts
   ```
2. Get development dependencies for Nautilus

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
   ```
3. Download Nautilus source - note that this command doesn't require sudo; also, it'll place multiple files to current directory so it's usually good idea to create an extra dir for that.

   ```
   mkdir nautilus
   cd nautilus
   apt-get source nautilus
   ```
4. The source will be downloaded and extracted to `nautilus-VERSION*` folder (VERSION is, of course some version number, most probably 2.32.something). Get into that folder.
5. Open file `src/file-manager/fm-desktop-icon-view.c`
6. Search for `GtkActionEntry desktop_view_entries[]` - in my case it's on line 721 however it may differ for your version. It should look like this:

   ```
   static const GtkActionEntry desktop_view_entries[] = {
       /* name, stock id */
       { "New Launcher Desktop", NULL,
         /* label, accelerator */
         N_("Create L_auncher..."), NULL,
         /* tooltip */
         N_("Create a new launcher"),
         G_CALLBACK (action_new_launcher_callback) },
       /* name, stock id */
       { "Change Background", NULL,
         /* label, accelerator */
         N_("Change Desktop _Background"), NULL,
         /* tooltip */
         N_("Show a window that lets you set your desktop background's pattern or color"),
         G_CALLBACK (action_change_background_callback) },
       /* name, stock id */
       { "Empty Trash Conditional", NULL,
         /* label, accelerator */
         N_("Empty Trash"), NULL,
         /* tooltip */
         N_("Delete all items in the Trash"),
         G_CALLBACK (action_empty_trash_conditional_callback) },
   };
   ```

   Note that the second array contains `Change Background` - remove it, so you get something like that:

   ```
   static const GtkActionEntry desktop_view_entries[] = {
       /* name, stock id */
       { "New Launcher Desktop", NULL,
         /* label, accelerator */
         N_("Create L_auncher..."), NULL,
         /* tooltip */
         N_("Create a new launcher"),
         G_CALLBACK (action_new_launcher_callback) },
       /* Change Background was here */
       /* name, stock id */
       { "Empty Trash Conditional", NULL,
         /* label, accelerator */
         N_("Empty Trash"), NULL,
         /* tooltip */
         N_("Delete all items in the Trash"),
         G_CALLBACK (action_empty_trash_conditional_callback) },
   };
   ```

   Save the file.
7. Back in Terminal cd to the source root (if you haven't do so already)

   ```
   cd nautilus-*
   ```

   And run

   ```
   dch -l local
   ```

   This will execute the default `$EDITOR` (probably Nano) with the changelog file prepared to input your changes. Write something descriptive after the `*`, keep everything else intact. Note that `-l local` option is to note local build, you can use anything else instead of `local`, however it's important to add entry to changelog, otherwise your local build would be overridden by repository version.
8. Compile and build the package

   ```
   debuild -i -us -uc -b
   ```

   For explanation of switches see [debuild man page Examples section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/debuild.1.html#contenttoc9)
9. Go grab some coffee, this might take some time.
10. Once the build finishes (hopefully with success), you'll find bunch of .deb packages in the parent directory. Install them all.

    ```
    cd ..
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    ```
11. Logout or restart Nautilus for great justice...

    ```
    nautilus -q
    ```

Look ma', no "Change Background"!

[image: nautilus desktop menu]

To be 100% sure, it's probably good idea to [lock `nautilus` package in Synaptic](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-lock-package-versions-from-synaptic-package-manager.html).

Edit: Once you've verified that everything is working fine, you can get rid of build-dep packages using [this nifty command](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/undo-apt-get-build-dep-remove-build.html). You just need to install `aptitude`...

#### References

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/20

Comment: It will be nice, if you say how to remove that option completely from right click.

Comment: Ok, I'll get into how to edit the Nautilus source and recompile it. Just a little time.

Comment: Here you go, I hope it'll be useful.

Comment: nice one @jnv :)

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. I see that Markdown screwed up source code from fm-desktop-icon-view.c, don't copy it yet.

Comment: Code should be fine now. Sorry for spamming your inboxes.

Comment: Good shot @jnv :) i will try your solution. You will be getting 500 points i guess :)

Comment: I am getting the following error, have a look @ it pls http://paste.ubuntu.com/628701/

Comment: As the last line suggests, run `sudo apt-get update`. Also, it seems you haven't updated system in a while so it's probably good idea to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I am getting error even after `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` http://paste.ubuntu.com/628791/ what version of ubuntu you are running?

Comment: I run Natty and you apparently run Maverick. Anyway, that really shouldn't matter. There's something bad about your APT and/or internet connection - from the output it seems that the downloaded archives are either incomplete or broken. Maybe using different (possibly closer) mirror could help.

Comment: Okay, let's give it a shot with different mirror - use [this howto](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-select-fastest-mirror-in-ubuntu.html) to find the fastest mirror with Synaptic. Then refresh the packages - either using Synaptic or `apt-get update`. If it ends up with error, please, show me an output. There's no reason to continue if data from repositories are invalid. I am sorry that this doesn't work so well, but these are problems beyond the scope of normal situation. You didn't have any problem installing software on other occurrences?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like a charm, the mistake what i have done  is i haven't checked source code in software sources after checking it the problem got resolved. But during installation i get the following output, is there any wrong in this output http://paste.ubuntu.com/629699/

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about `deb-src`... That's just an output from `shared-mime-info`, you can ignore that.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate all those debian files into one, so that it will be little easier for us..

Comment: Installing `nautilus_2.*.deb` package should be enough, since there are no changes which would break compatibility with stock Nautilus packages. However, you should be very conservative when updating Nautilus-related packages.

Comment: Also, you need to be sure that all target systems use the same version of Nautilus you have customized. Installing all those custom-built packages make things somewhat safer and installation process can be automated - just pack all those .deb packages to one archive and extract&install them using a shell script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and finally if we need that option how to bring it back. We need to edit that source code again or we have someother way?

Comment: Just reinstall the stock package from repository, e.g. with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus/maverick` - that `/maverick` is a hint you want to "downgrade" to repository package, otherwise apt-get will complain about being unable to download the package (because it was installed locally).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to do that, but I presume that the desktop background is set via a GConf key. If so, you can run gconf-editor as root, find the relevant key, and set it as mandatory. Then, users won't be allowed to change its value.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** *I have not used Sabayon (User Profile Editor in Ubuntu) or Pesullus (Lock Down Editor in Ubuntu). Just helping  out by pointing you in the right direction.* :-)

http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/

**Sabayon** is a system administration tool to define and deploy desktop profiles for the GNOME desktop environment. It allows you to control such things as panel layouts, menu items, default gconf settings, as well as provide pre-defined defaults for some non-GNOME programs such as Firefox. It also makes use of the lockdown functionality of Pessulus. It does this by providing a "desktop within a window", allowing you to customize your desktop as you see fit, then recording your changes, to be applied to users by the sabayon-apply program at login time.

Who should use Sabayon?
Sabayon is geared towards anyone who has need of providing a standardized GNOME desktop to their end users. Teachers who administer labs, Libraries, and Businesses all have need to have a "locked down" desktop, and can make good use of Sabayon

It is in **Ubuntu Software Centre**, do a **search** for "**user profile editor**"
It will be placed in **System>Administration>User Profile Editor**

Run the program, click **add** button, type **Student**, click **add**, click **edit**, Click **Help**, click **contents**. **Read the help**.

Here is another site that explains it a bit more, with emphasis on a Kiosk.

http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/ubuntu01.htm

Other programs that allow you to lock down things are "**Lock Down Editor**" found in Ubuntu Software Centre (It is actually called **Pessulus**, don't know why Ubuntu calls it Lock Down Editor.)

The other is **Ubuntu Tweak**, found at http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

I think Sabayon (User Profile Editor in Ubuntu) will be your best bet.

**P.S.** Here is another discussion on your question....
http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/1626/

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier, just set the gconf key as mandatory. Here's one [how-to](http://www.novell.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=7007945).

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source \
xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type string --set \
/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename \ 
"/usr/share/backgrounds/cosmos/blue-marble-west.jpg"
```

For Ubuntu 11.10 and later (or using Gnome 3), set the dconf key as mandatory. See the end of this [article](https://live.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators).

Answer (score 2):

By changing permissions of

```
sudo chmod 660 /usr/bin/gnome-appearance-properties #or any other permission
```

you can restrict access to modifications of theme or background properties. However this will **not** remove the menu entry.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **Gofris**, this application is equal to deepfreeze on wind*ws. you probably noticed that any changes you make to their system: create or delete files, settings and so on, everything resets when you restart the computer.

*do following action to install **Gofris** on ubuntu :*

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tldm217/gofris
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install gofris-en

> type **gofris-en** in terminal to
> running.

[image]

check this link : http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/ofris-gets-appindicator-gofris-deep.html

Answer (score 2):

I make it work with gconftool-2. Just run:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/lockdown/disable_context_menus 1
```

If you need this for all users, just create a /etc/profile.d script.