# How to lock network settings and desktop wallpaper for non-sudo users

Tags: networking, desktop-background, configuration-management

Question solved:

I ended up using dconf since Ubuntu Desktop natively uses the GNOME desktop. For any people unfamiliar with it, you can edit dconf settings via terminal or GUI. I ended up doing it via the terminal with the use of the following link @steeldriver mentioned in a comment: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en

Network settings will be locked behind a privilege wall by default I discovered after testing with a non-sudo account (stupid, i know..) so I did not have to adjust any settings on that.

---

For a school assignment I have been asked to lock the following three settings in place on both Windows and Linux workstations:

- Network Configuration (e.g. not being able to change IP's, DNS servers)
- Desktop Wallpaper
- Trusted sites (for this question not relevant since Trusted Sites is a Internet Explorer specific feature)

I know I can do this via Windows with GPO's, but I am unsure how to push this with Ubuntu Server 19.04. There are programs like Chef and Ansible, but both seem like very big packages for just these two specific settings. The users will be working on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.

The Ubuntu workstation will be joined to a Windows Server AD and will need access to network shares. I believe the AD-integration and Samba will be able to fulfill this need, but I am bending my head over the GPO part.

I looked into SSSD, but I can't find if these two specific GPO settings are supported within Linux.

Most ideally any new deployed workstations would automatically take over these settings, but I'm not sure if that is realistic. Should I look into a bash-script that automatically runs upon logging in to set these settings static?

Comment: 1. Ubuntu server doesn't have a network manager. 2. Ubuntu server doesn't have a wallpaper or a desktop. Problem solved!

Comment: For the wallpaper, it's going to depend what desktop session your users are using - but in the case of gnome-based desktops at least, you can use dconf locks. See for example [Lock down specific settings](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en)

Comment: @mikewhatever I mentioned the term workstations, so I was hoping for a solution for Ubuntu Desktop. Having users work via a terminal is not a solution unfortunately.

Comment: I quote "...but I am unsure how to do this with Ubuntu Server 19.04. "

Comment: @mikewhatever My apologies, I further clarified the question. I was hoping for a Ubuntu Server to be able to push any rulesets to the Ubuntu Desktop workstations. If not possible, I would like to know what settings I can adjust locally to lock these settings down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 3 type of permissions that you can restricted to *non-sudo* users :

- Read       (r)
- Write      (w)
- Execution  (x)

Each files and folder had 3 "types" (I don't know how to spell it) :

- Owner
- Group (group where owner is)
- Others

and also :

- All

Each permission can be removed on a file with the following command :

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/passwd
```

In this example, I removed the **execution** permission for each user. If you want to remove only at *others*, just add the **o** before `-x` like that :

```
sudo chmod o-x /etc/passwd
```

So to summarize how to removed each permission, use the 1rst letter of the permission (same for who you want to affect) *execution use the **x** instead of **e***

NB : to do it on a folder and his files inside, just dd the `-R` option (for recursivity), but be careful, it can destroy your OS

NB-2 : You can see current permission on files/folders with `ls -l`

**Edit** : Here is a link to [remove the right to change Background Wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34803/how-to-remove-change-desktop-background-from-right-click)

Comment: How does that help in restricting the wallpaper selected by the user?

Comment: @SimonSudler just need to remove **rw** permission on `/usr/share/backgrounds` folder (if it's on this folder into Ubuntu Server)

Comment: @damadam Could I use the same method to use a file down like Netplan, or would that still allow users to change settings via the GUI?

Comment: @cediscal to be able to use a file down, you need to have **rw** permissions (or only **w** right if you just want to add another file)

Comment: @damadam on my gnome desktop, I can select a wallpaper from every location I want to... `/usr/share/backgrounds` is just the default location. https://vitux.com/8-ways-to-customize-your-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: @SimonSudler edit answer